# Unable to authenticate to company LDAP using flask-ldap3-login in Docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, docker-compose, ldap

I`m trying to connect to my company's LDAP server to authenticate users in my flask web app. I'm constantly getting this error:

```
2020-06-22 09:55:07,459 ERROR flask_ldap3_login MainThread : no active server available in server pool after maximum number of tries
```

I also tried to telnet to the ldap server from the web container and not connection can be made. What do I need to do to allow my containers to run on our network to be able to access LDAP?
I tried enabling SSL and added the certs, but still no success.

docker-compose file

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        build: ./application/db
        container_name: dqm_db
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    web:
        build: .
        container_name: dqm_web
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
            - 389:389
            - 636:636
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - db
        links:
            - redis
        volumes:
            - .:/data-quality-management

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: dqm_nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
        depends_on:
          - web

    redis:
        container_name: dqm_redis
        env_file:
            - .env
        image: redis:latest
        restart: always
        command: redis-server
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        volumes:
            - .:/data-quality-management

    worker:
        build: .
        hostname: worker
        container_name: dqm_worker
        entrypoint: celery
        command: -A application.run_celery:celery worker --loglevel=info
        links:
            - redis
            - web
        depends_on:
            - web
            - redis
        env_file:
            - .env
        volumes:
            - .:/data-quality-management

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python-dev  -y
RUN apt-get install libsasl2-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libldap2-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev -y
RUN apt-get clean -y

WORKDIR /data-quality-management

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY requirements.txt .

EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 389
EXPOSE 636

COPY *.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
RUN update-ca-certificates

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /data-quality-management

CMD gunicorn -w $WEB_CONCURRENCY -b $WEB_BIND wsgi:app
```